# Unexpected behaviour with UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState

Tags: ios

I'm trying to implement multistage animation using UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState to allow the user to cancel the animation at will. The animation is a view that continually and cyclically animates between two sizes. When the user touches the view to cancel the animation, I want the view to quickly revert back to its original, small size, whether it was growing or shrinking at the time.

I'm implementing the multistaging aspect by having two separate animations, one for growing the view and one for shrinking it. Each calls the other routine in its completion block, thus cycling forever unless the abort flag has been set.

I get the expected behaviour if abort is called during the grow-the-view animation: the animation quickly and immediately returns the view to its original, small size and stops. Good!

However, if abort is called during the shrink-the-view animation cycle, the view continues to shrink at the same speed (and then stops as expected), as if the UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState option was never invoked.

Code will hopefully make this clearer and hopefully somebody can see what I can't.

```
- (void)stopAnimating {
    abort = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 // some small interval
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{ self.frame = minRect;}
                     completion:^(BOOL done){}
     ];
}

- (void)animateSmall {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{self.frame = minRect;}
                     completion:^(BOOL done){if (!abort)[self animateBig];}
     ];
}

- (void)animateBig {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction

                     animations:^{self.frame = maxRect;}
                     completion:^(BOOL done){if (!abort)[self animateSmall];}
     ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess here, because your code looks exactly as I would have done it.  But I think what's going on is that the abort animation is setting the same attribute to the same value as the animation it's interrupting, and this gets treated as equivalent and not in need of change (even though the duration changes).

A test of this theory - and a fix to the problem - would be to make your oscillating minRect just a little bit different in size than your steady state minRect.

Hope this works.  Good luck.

Comment: I think you've got it. Still, one minor puzzle. If I change the final size slightly using an explicit CGRect newMinRect = CGRectMake(...), the code does the appropriate thing during the shrinking phase. However if I change the minRect functionally to the exact same value, using CGRectOffset(minRect,...), there's still some unexpected behaviour as the rectangle shrinks. The origin of the rectangle shifts either leftward or rightward of where it's expected to be during the shift, depending on how long I wait before calling abort, before finishing at the expected final x-position. Very odd.

Comment: It's hard to visualize, but I think you're probably looking for inset rather than offset, like this: self.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.frame, UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 1, 1, 1));

Comment: You might still be seeing the weirdness, though.  Again on a hunch, what if you try that inset trick on your oscillating min rectangle, not on your final state rect?  (and of course, don't inset it over and over, just once outside of the animation loop).

Comment: No joy I'm afraid. Still the weird effects. And inset vs. offset shouldn't make a difference, should it? As long as the frame is varied slightly. But that looks moot anyway.

Comment: Maybe try some NSLogging inside the animation block to see if the rect matches your expectation.  The other thing you may already know about is the debug menu on the simulator has an item called "Toggle Slow Animations".  If you use that, it might reveal a hint that your eye was missing.

Comment: Another clue: I tried aborting the cyclic animation by animating the bounds to {{0,0},{oldW+1, oldH+1}}, assuming that the left origin would remain fixed in place (which is what I wanted) Instead, both the shrinking and the growing rects reached the minimum width almost immediately (essentially snapping the left edge toward the right), before finishing by moving the entire rectangle to its proper x-position at the left. I don't know if that's clear or not, but what it seems to be saying for the original problem is that the origin is animating at a different velocity than the width.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9162/discussion-between-hkatz-and-danh)